# Add 4 image in imageview and change the picture with tap or swipe gesture

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

I want to add four image in image view. at first one image will be visible.

And whenever tap or swipe on image view it will change the image.

i want to change the image of imageview 4 times one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ToggleImageView.h

```
@interface ToggleImageView : UIImageView {
    NSArray *images;
    int currentIndex;
}

- (id)initWithImages:(NSArray *)theImages;

@end
```

ToggleImageView.m

```
#import "ToggleImageView.h"

@implementation ToggleImageView

- (id)initWithImages:(NSArray *)theImages {
    self = [self initWithImage:[theImages objectAtIndex:0]];

    if (self) {
        images = [theImages retain];
        currentIndex = 0;

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:tap];
        [tap release];

        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [images release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (images.count > 0) {
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex > images.count - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
        }

        self.image = [images objectAtIndex:currentIndex];
    }
}

@end
```

And then somewhere in your controller

```
ToggleImageView *tv = [[ToggleImageView alloc] initWithImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"], nil]];
[self.view addSubview:tv];
[tv release];
```

Comment: ToggleImageView *tv = [[ToggleImageView alloc] initWithImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"], nil]];
[self.view addSubview:tv];
[tv release];  where this code i have put .......because uiimageview  doesn't support viewDidLoad

Comment: where should i use this last three line of code

Comment: loadView or viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear or any setup method you created yourself.

Comment: @virendra You put these in the viewDidLoad of your ViewController

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
 ToggleImageView *tv = [[ToggleImageView alloc] initWithImages:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4"], nil]];
 [self.view addSubview:tv];
 [tv release];

} giving error view not a union or structure

Comment: Sounds to me that you put the code in a class that is not extending a UIViewController. Good read: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I want to move or swipe images in both right and left direction. So what to do for right direction??

Comment: In stead of a UITapGestureRecognizer, use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer, and in the 'handleSwipe', increase or decrease the index depending on the direction of the swipe